# I have apple auth token while trying to integrate apple login in RoR application. I need to extract emailId from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, token, decode, apple-sign-in

While decoding in  jwt.io site I can see emailId info there but with jwt gems not getting what I want. Any ideas how to extract this info in ROR application.

For decoding I trying this

decode_token = JWT.decode apple_token, "", true, { algorithm: 'HS256'}

Comment: What data you are encoding? Also, provide the decode and encode logic in your question.

Comment: This apple token is coming from apple to our RoR app. Encoding is all from apple side. In order to store/create user we need email Id extracted from it. I have updated the question with my decoding logic. Please advice.

Comment: Do you get an error, or just an empty data? My guess is that apple tokens do not use `HS256` as the signing algorithm (which is a symmetric signing). When you peek at the token in jwt.io you can check the algorithm used - it's `alg` claim in the header.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I do see an error as `Completed 409 Conflict in 5ms (Views: 0.2ms | Process.pid: 28974)` . And while simply pasting the token in jwt.io I can see `alg` claim as `RS256`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple tokens are signed with a `RS256` algorithm, so you should use that algorithm to verify and decode their tokens. You will also need Apple's public key in order to verify signatures.

Apple exposes a JWKS url, where it publishes their public keys: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys

You can use [this example](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#retrieve-rsa-signing-keys-from-a-jwks-endpoint) to see how to decode a token with a public key downloaded from a JWKS endpoint.

You can also skip signature verification, and only decode the token: `jwt.decode(apple_token, options={"verify_signature": False})` but you should be careful with this approach - anyone can forge an Apple token and will be able to impersonate any user. You can use this method for example for dev purposes.